# Is there a way to get the current url action?

Tags: url, commerce-cloud

I am using URLUtils to generate URL's for a languages selector as per the documentation. However I want to use the current URL so that a redirect will go to the same page in a different locale. The example in the document has a hardcoded "Home-Show" action:

```
<a class="" href="${URLUtils.http(new dw.web.URLAction('Home-Show',dw.system.Site.getCurrent().getID(),locale))}"><isprint value="${localeLanguage}"></a>
```

Is there a way to get the current action including any url paramters, or will this requires a custom function to extract this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the current URL as follows, if you are not using SFRA:

```
pdict.CurrentSession.clickStream.last.referer
```

Otherwise, you can get the `clickStream` from the `session` in SFRA.

Does this solve your issue?